# Put a middleware-like between RazorPage and UrlHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm working on an multilingual website. earlier, i used to use `QueryStringRequestProvider` for `RequestLocalizationOptions`. Finally, based on some SEO-friendly best practices i decided to migrate to `RouteDataRequestCultureProvider`. I have many problems in this way. i've already checked more than 100 github issues and stackoverflow posts to find a working solution, but still nothing.

Currently i used these codes to partial reach the goal

**Startup.cs**

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureRequestLocalization();
                options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider
                {
                    RouteDataStringKey = LanguageRouteConstraint.Key,
                    Options = options
                });
            });
services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.Conventions.Add(new LocalizedPageRouteModelConvention());
                });
```

**LanguageRouteConstraint.cs**

```
 public class LanguageRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        public const string Key = "culture";
        public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            if (!values.ContainsKey(Key))
                return false;

            var lang = values[routeKey] as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lang))
                return false;

            return lang == "tr" || lang == "en" || lang == "fa";
        }
    }
```

**Cultures.cs**

```
 public static class Cultures
    {
        public static readonly string[] Supported = { "tr", "en", "fa" };
        public static readonly string Default = Supported[0];

        public static RequestLocalizationOptions ConfigureRequestLocalization(this RequestLocalizationOptions options)
        {
            options ??= new RequestLocalizationOptions();
            var supportedCultures = Supported
                 .Select(culture => new CultureInfo(culture))
                 .ToList();

            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(Default, Default);
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            return options;
        }
    }
```

**LocalizedPageRouteModelConvention.cs**

```
public class LocalizedPageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
    {
        
        public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
        {
          
            foreach (var selector in model.Selectors.ToList())
            {
                model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
                {
                    AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                    {
                        Order = -1,
                        Template = AttributeRouteModel
                            .CombineTemplates("{" + LanguageRouteConstraint.Key + "?}",
                                selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template),
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

The major problem of mine, is currently i dont have a working way to put a middleware between IUrlHelper and RazorPage link generator

Now, i can use as below:

```
var currentCulture = Request.RouteValues[LanguageRouteConstraint.Key];
                Url.Page("/Index/Contact", new {culture= currentCulture});
```

but it doesn't make sense to trace codes in project from the scratch to change code from `Url.Page("")` to `Url.Page("", new{culture=ANY})`

As i said before, i checked many sites, but still i got nothing.

The only thing i need for now, is a **WORKING WAY** to use standard `Url.Page()`, that to be translated to `Url.Page("", new{culture=ANY})` in background.

Thanks in advance

***My problem is only about RazorPages, not Controllers***

Comment: Can't you just create your own `Url.CulturePage()` extension that just calls `Url.Page()`?

Comment: @mxmissile i've already created a custom function as `Url.PageCultured()` and works properly. but this ideas is something like that `Url.Page("", new {culture=ANY})`. i should look for that everywhere in project, and it will certainly take many times to do

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+H` and UI tests are your friend here.

Comment: Now i've found a way. i think it's best way for now to create a `CustomRazorPage : RazorPage<object>` and inherit pages